# Where can I find the latest version of XNA to download?

Tags: xna

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I after searching for XNA Download on google, I found this page:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xna/archive/2010/09/16/xna-game-studio-4-0-available-for-download.aspx

Following the link there, I get to this page:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/SiteError.aspx?404;aspx&404;http://create.msdn.com:80/launchcenter?lc=1033

So this is kind of confusing for someone starting out.

- What is the latest **release** version of XNA I can use for PC/WP7 game development?
- Where can I find the installer to download it?

I don't need a bootstrapper to download Visual Studio for me, as I already has the IDE installed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: [Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9ac86eca-206f-4274-97f2-ef6c8b1f478f) download.

Also see [Windows Phone Developer Tools: Offline ISO Image](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=201927).

But note that the Web Installer available [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started) will only download and install what you need. Since you already have Visual Studio, it will just integrate itself nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is XNA 4.0. The bootstrapper is a smart installer and only installs the components you are missing. For example if you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate then it is not going to install the Express version as well. It also includes a Windows Phone emulator if you are interested in that. And here's the [direct link to the installer](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/7/177D6AF8-17FA-40E7-AB53-00B7CED31729/vm_web.exe).